# DROOLS::Rules getting executed even when the condition specifed is not satisfied

Tags: drools

Below is the rule:

---

```
rule "RelStatusUpdateCalcCheck"
salience 55
no-loop true
when    
$evt : UpdateRateStatusReq(statusID == RateStatusEnum.READY.getValue() || == RateStatusEnum.HOLIDAY_ROLL_FORWARD.getValue() || == RateStatusEnum.ROLL_FORWARD.getValue()) from entry-point RequestStream
$rr : ReliableRate(rateId == $evt.getRateID())
$dr : DerivedRate(holidayFlag == false, grfLock == false, $lr : listInputRateId, $lr.contains($evt.getRateID()))    
then
cepService.relStatusUpdateCalcCheck($evt, $rr, $dr);

end**
```

---

The last condition states that if 'holidayflag' is false and other conditions are satisfied as well then only execute the the java method. But the method gets executed even when the holidayflag is true. Only when I restart my app server the method doesnt get executed when holidayflag is true. Why is this so?

Comment: If it's behaving correctly after restarting the server, what's the issue?Without knowing much about your application I would guess that it has been written to only load the knowledge base on startup. It is possible to reload the knowledge base at runtime if that's the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Thanks for the reply. I got the root cause of this issue. Actually when I update the holidayFlag to 'true',the DerivedRate object is updated but the Drools session is never updated as the result of which when the rules gets executed it still refers to the old value. When I restart my app I load the Facts again that's why this issue gets resolved after restart.

Below is the code that i added in order to resolve this issue::
DerivedRate dr = (DerivedRate) qd.iterator().next().get("dr");
FactHandle fh = session.getFactHandle(dr);  --> new code
dr.setHolidayFlag(true);
session.update(fh, dr);      --> new code
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible explanation is

You have multiple DerivedRate facts in your working memory and these facts match against your rules because of either:

- You insert these facts because of a programming error (like, accessing a static instance of knowledge base from multiple threads)
- You use a statefull knowledge session and DerivedRate facts are leftovers from previous operations.